# server install from iso using apt-cacher server

Tags: installation, server, apt, preinstallation, apt-cacher

I have a server running apt-cacher. Is there any way to specify it as an apt source while doing a Ubuntu server install from iso? I'm currently doing a minimum install and then modifying /etc/apt/sources.list. I'm looking for something similar to the `vmbuilder --mirror` option. Currently using the 12.04.02 iso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the setup, you can specify a custom repo URL in the repo selection screen. So you just enter an address pointing to apt-cacher server there for example `http://apt-cacher:3142/mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu`

Comment: I must be missing this configuration screen? I'm starting the install with the 'minimal server virtual machine' option...

Comment: ah, it may be entered in the http proxy configuration settings. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: for anyone coming across this post down the road, it looks like it saves this setting in /etc/apt/apt.conf as a single line `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://apt-cacher:3142/";`

Comment: Yes, entering it in http proxy setting should work too since apt-cacher is in itself a caching proxy server. On another note, you might to switch apt-cacher-ng, it's lot better than apt-cacher (https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/)

Comment: "should work too"? I must still be overlooking the configuration option during install. Is there another setting I may be missing? The vmbuilder script results in a modified sources.list which is what I'm familiar with, it would be nice to keep it consistent should my caching server change in the future.